# How to install omniORB for python3?

Tags: python-3.x, omniorb

I could get omniORB running in python2.7 by just executing the configure script.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/usr/local/bin$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
ubuntu@ubuntu:/usr/local/bin$ python2
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import omniORB
>>>
```

However, running

```
../configure PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
```

didn't do the trick for python3:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/usr/local/bin$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import omniORB
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'omniORB'
>>>
```

When running `../configure` without any options, the script outputs:

```
...
checking for python... /usr/bin/python
checking for python version... 2.7
checking for python platform... linux2
...
```

When running `../configure PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3` , the script outputs:

```
...
checking for python version... 3.5
checking for python platform... linux
checking for python script directory... ${prefix}/lib/python3.5/site-packages
...
```

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and the latest omniorb 4.2.2.

Comment: You only ran `configure`, not `make` and `make install` afterwards?

Comment: sure. In both cases i ran `make` and `make install` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem too (I'm using ubuntu 18.04 and omniORB 4.2.3).

In my case, omniORBpy was installed in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages, but the directory is not in python's sys.path.

You should check sys.path and where omniORBpy is installed.